# Getting error for inserting xml data into database table using C#

Tags: c#

I am just trying to insert my xml data into a table through calling a stored procedure. I doubt something is wrong in my xml and that is why I am getting the error.

My xml is bit large & here I am showing just parts of it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'   xmlns:ns='http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v9' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:ProcessShipmentRequest>
            <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                <ns:UserCredential>
                    <ns:Key>aaaaaa</ns:Key>
                    <ns:Password>aaaaaa</ns:Password>
                </ns:UserCredential>
            </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ns:ClientDetail>
                <ns:AccountNumber>aaaaaa</ns:AccountNumber>
                <ns:MeterNumber>aaaaaa</ns:MeterNumber>
            </ns:ClientDetail>
            <ns:TransactionDetail>
                <ns:CustomerTransactionId>ProcessShipmentRequest_DG_HAL</ns:CustomerTransactionId>
            </ns:TransactionDetail>
            <ns:Version>
                <ns:ServiceId>ship</ns:ServiceId>
                <ns:Major>9</ns:Major>
                <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
                <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
            </ns:Version>
            <ns:RequestedShipment>
                <ns:ShipTimestamp>2011-11-03T06:50:40</ns:ShipTimestamp>
                <ns:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns:DropoffType>
                <ns:ServiceType>FEDEX_GROUND</ns:ServiceType>
                <ns:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns:PackagingType>
                <ns:TotalWeight>
                     <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
                     <ns:Value>1.0</ns:Value>
                </ns:TotalWeight>
                <ns:Shipper>
                     <ns:AccountNumber>aaaaaa</ns:AccountNumber>
                     <ns:Contact>
                          <ns:CompanyName>test</ns:CompanyName>
                          <ns:PhoneNumber>11111111</ns:PhoneNumber>
                     </ns:Contact>
                     <ns:Address>
```

Here is my c# code for calling the stored procedure to insert data into table

```
private void SaveData(string CompanyName, string Attention, string Address1, string Address2, string Country, string PostalCode, string City, string State, string Telephone, string UPSService, bool isInsured, string IdentificationNo,  string RequestXml, string ResponseXml)
{
        Database DB = GlobalObjects.GetInstance().DB;

        using (DbCommand cmd = DB.GetStoredProcCommand("InsLabelDetail"))
        {
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@IdentificationNo", DbType.String, IdentificationNo);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@CompanyName", DbType.String, CompanyName);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@Attention", DbType.String, Attention);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@add1", DbType.String, Address1);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@add2", DbType.String, Address2);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@Country", DbType.String, Country);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@PostalCode", DbType.String, PostalCode);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@City", DbType.String, City);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@State", DbType.String, State);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@Telephone", DbType.String, Telephone);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@UPSService", DbType.String, UPSService);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@isInsured", DbType.Int32, (isInsured==true ? 1 : 0));
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@shipto", DbType.String, Country);
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@RequestXML", DbType.Xml, RequestXml.Replace("encoding='UTF-8'", string.Empty));
            DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "@ResponseXML", DbType.Xml, ResponseXml.Replace("encoding='UTF-8'", string.Empty));

            try
            {
                DB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

The error or the exception I am getting is :

> XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding

Please tell me where I made the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a parsing error related to UTF-8, UTF-16 encodings. That means you must show us the data that parse that xml. 
With a lucky guess, I can say that you must change the code that you read the xml data with manual encoding switching. 
For Example:

```
XmlDocument _document = new XmlDocument();
_document.LoadXml(_xmlString);
XmlDeclaration _declaration = (XmlDeclaration)_document.FirstChild;
_declaration.Encoding = "UTF-16";
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try removing the line  and see.

If it is successful then its comes down to the problem that xml in database is stored as UTF-16 and you are trying to insert using UTF-8.

Hope the information helps you.

Comment: 1) i just do not understand what line i have to remove? 2)do i need to change encoding='UTF-8' from encoding='UTF-16' ?

Comment: You need to change the encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-16

Comment: The above code is loading the xml into a Document object and then setting its UTF encoding to UTF-16. If you have the Xml as a string then changing it to UTF-16 directly and then passing it to the DB should solve it. Else try using tools like Xml Spy and change the encoding of the xml validate if its a valid xml and once its valid try to persist it to the database.